# convert arabic string to utf8 encoded url

Tags: php, regex

lets assume that i have a  string as the following:
إصلاح إصلاح 
and i want to convert it to seo friendly url removing slashes and special characters with the following function calls

```
$title = trim(strtolower($str));  
$title = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9\s-]#',null, $title); 
$title = preg_replace('#[\s-]+#','-', $title);
```

in English its working fine and its giving correct results but in arabic its giving the following result :
15731589160415751581-15731589160415751581

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Seems to work](http://codepad.viper-7.com/kuIlno)? That's against 5.4 but works the same against 5.2 / 5.3.

Comment: did you try arabic characters ?

Comment: I used the characters you posted.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest `urlencode()` with unique post id, like

```
/blog/12345-<?= urlencode('إصلاح إصلاح') ?>
```

Comment: with urlencode spaces and special characters are not removed i want to remove them

Comment: ok. then you have to make another function - for convert arabic strings into transliterated latin, check this: http://mylanguages.org/arabic_romanization.php

Answer (score 2):

This is an unsolved problem yet. What you basically had to do is to transliterate any given character (irrelevant if arabic or chinese or japanese or whatever) to latin transcription and then perform the URI generation methods on it.

There is some basic(!) support in iconv for this, have a look at http://ch.php.net/manual/de/function.iconv.php, you have to use `iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $text)` but as I said, support is limited.

If I were you I would just remove spaces and such and then call `urlencode()` on it:

```
$url = urlencode(mb_ereg_replace('\s+', '-', $url));
```

I'm using `mb_ereg_replace()` because it is unicode aware and such replaces unicode whitespaces as well.

Comment: `$url = preg_replace('#\s+#u', '-', $url)` is PCRE with UTF-8 support enabled.

Comment: can you take a look at this website and see his links [link](http://www.altibbi.com/)

Comment: @rodneyrehm but it is not very well defined what is matched by \s in pcre. Have a look at the manpage, by default it performes the ``isspace()`` check and that is true for space, formfeed, newline, carriage return, horizontal tab, and vertical tab.

Comment: @rodneyrehm did u try it on IE9 am getting nothing

Answer (score 1):

The unicode property for arabic letter is : `\p{arabic}`, change the second preg_replace by:

```
$title = preg_replace('#[^\p{arabic}\s-]#',null, $title);
```

Comment: Warning: preg_replace(): Compilation failed: unknown property name after \P or \p at offset 11 in /usr/share/nginx/html/url.php on line 34

Comment: @user1268911: May be a version problem, see: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46800

Answer (score 1):

Try This function. I always use it and it works perfectly!

```
function SafeUrl3($str) {
    $friendlyURL = htmlentities($str, ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8", false) ;
    $friendlyURL = preg_replace ( "/[^أ-يa-zA-Z0-9_.-]/u", "-", $friendlyURL ) ;
    $friendlyURL = html_entity_decode($friendlyURL,ENT_COMPAT, "UTF-8") ;
    $friendlyURL = trim($friendlyURL, '-') ;

    return $friendlyURL ;
}
```